# Merge all rows and columns from different tables using SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, union

How can I merge all columns and all rows from different tables? The tables may have different column names. Here's a toy example:

```
CREATE TABLE "table_1" (ID INTEGER, length INTEGER, width INTEGER)
CREATE TABLE "table_2" (ID INTEGER, width INTEGER, height INTEGER)

INSERT INTO table_1 (ID, length, width) VALUES (1, 10, 40), (2, 20, 50), (3, 30, 60)
INSERT INTO table_2 (ID, width, height) VALUES (4, 100, 130), (5, 110, 140), (6, 120, 150)
```

Tables are as follows:

```
table_1
ID     length     width
1      10         40
2      20         50
3      30         60

table_2
ID     width      height
4      100        130
5      110        140
6      120        150
```

I am looking for the following result:

```
table_result
ID     length     width     height
1      10         40        NULL
2      20         50        NULL
3      30         60        NULL
4      NULL       100       130
5      NULL       110       140
6      NULL       120       150
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `union all`:

```
select id, length, width, null as height from table_1
union all select id, null, width, height from table_2
```

If there are duplicate `id`s across the two tables and you want them on the same row:

```
select id, max(length) as length, max(width) as width, max(height) as height
from (
    select id, length, width, null as height from table_1
    union all select id, null, width, height from table_2
) t
group by id
```